# How to run the qcluster process in production (Django-q)?

Tags: django, django-q

I have a Django webapp. The app has some scheduled tasks, for this I'm using django-q. In local development you need to run manage.py qcluster to be able to run the scheduled tasks.

How can I automatically run the qcluster process in production?

I'm deploying to a Digital Ocean droplet, using ubuntu, nginx and gunicorn.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Procfile?

My configuration is to have a Procfile that contains:

```
web: python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
worker: python ./manage.py qcluster
```

This way, every time the web process is started, another process for django-q is also created.

Comment: How to do this without a proc file? I would like the django-q cluster to start when the django server is started automatically and stop when the django server is stopped. Currently I'm facing the follwing issues:

- Running the django-q cluster from command line and stopping the same using CTRL + C is not stopping the cluster properly
- Even after the django server is stopped, since the cluster is running, schedules configured are running